# winform to GTK# for Mono

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono, gtk

I have created a C# application with 50 forms.

Unfortunately Mono (Mac OS version) doesn't work with standard window winform.

I don't know why, but I this moment I need to solve the problem.

The only solution seem convert winform to GTK#, but I don't have any experience on GTK#.

My questions are:

- How hard is convert my 50 forms to GTK# ?
- What I need to do exactly ?

This is an easy solution ? Or I need to re-write my application ?

Apart this I don't know where I can found/use an Visual IDE to do a design modification like Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: rewriting to another GUI framework is never easy. maybe you should focus on why Mono doesn't work, it should be pretty compatible with winform.

Comment: Mono's WinForms support in fact works on Linux. If it fails on OS X, you are supposed to report the bugs. If the Mono guys fix them, then you don't have to switch to another UI stack. http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

Answer (score 1):

GTK is a pretty good framework, on both windows and linux, GTK# is very easy to write by hand or to **[design](http://monodevelop.com/Stetic_GUI_Designer)** using **[monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)**.  So it is worth a shot if you are curious, GTK# apps are generally **[easier to find help for](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide)** ( the GTK+ docs are helpful )

The nicest thing about GTK# is the automatic layouts, no more crazy panel placement or absolute positioning like in winforms.

I am curious though why your winforms app isn't working, Mono's winforms support is pretty good and very near exactly matching .Net. What errors do you have?

Comment: There are too many errors with winform on MAC OS, the application is unstable there is no way to fix this issue. Probably my question don't have sense becouse migrate from winform to GTK# is certainly not easy and need time.

Comment: It sounds like you have a number of bugs and should report them to the mono folks,  If you winforms app works on .Net, the winforms parts should work equally well on OSX or linux. What version of mono are you using?

Comment: the application work fine on .net and mono for windows but not on MAC. I have asked on mono forum and they confirm me that MONO winform GUI don't work on MAC.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had with Winforms at Mono was that in the files "xyz.designer.cs" there is often a code:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(xyz)).BeginInit();
```

and

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(xyz)).EndInit();
```

looks like Mono does not accept this code.
My impression is that this code could be deleted from most of the windows forms. But I am not really sure.
For sure the "xyz.designer.cs" file cannot be modified under Visual studio since this code is automatically created by the GUI designer.
But you could modify these files under Monodevelop.
Looks like you would need to manually update 50 files.